# How to show ads right when the users starts the app in android?

Tags: android, admob

I have managed to show ads when the user pauses and resumes into the app (home then again returning to the app) but I want to show it when the user starts the app How can I achieve that

I have implemented with the help of this Guide
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open?hl=en-GB

Comment: check it out https://developers.google.com/admob/android/app-open

Comment: `AppOpenAd` will not be shown on a cold start. On a cold start, you can show a progress bar screen like a SplashScreen, load your Interstitial & show but this can take some time & may degrade user experience.